# Trouble making a GUI. Labels, spinners and buttons not appearing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I've put quite a few objects into this `JFrame`. however many of them do not appear until I hover them mainly the button as well as the `JTextField`. I only included the `JSpinner` components so that it wasn't so long. Is there anything in my spinners or lacking with my spinners that would make them not appear?
I've stripped it down alot so that it is just one textfield. Still nothing shows up. I've put everything in panels, however still nothing shows up.

```
public static void screen() {
    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Yore");
    myFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    myFrame.setResizable(false);
    myFrame.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    myFrame.setSize(300,365);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    myFrame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    myFrame.setContentPane(panel);
    JTextField Username = new JTextField();
    Username.setText("Username");
    Username.setColumns(10);
    panel.add(Username);

    }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). **My first guess is that this is the core of the problem. But I don't like guessing - so post an MCVE.**

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll keep that in mind. Thank you for the advice to use layout managers I'll try that right now.

Comment: *"Anything else you would suggest?"* Post an MCVE.

Comment: Note: An MCVE / SSCCE is ***not*** uncompilable code snippets. Please read the documents again, carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i forgot pne statement.

```
public static void screen() {
    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Yore");
    myFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    myFrame.setResizable(false);
    myFrame.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    myFrame.setSize(300,365);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    myFrame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    myFrame.setContentPane(panel);
    JTextField Username = new JTextField();
    Username.setText("Username");
    Username.setColumns(10);
    panel.add(Username); 

  panel.validate();

  }
```

Comment: You sir just made this work for me! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a layout manager for the frame. Also, add a JPanel to the frame and add all of the Spinners to the Panel.

Using the correct layout manager, you can programatically add the Spinners to the Panel, so that you do not need to hard code the bounds. You will also have the ability to have them resize as the window resizes, for example.

Take a look here to get started with layout managers. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Ok, so I backed everything up and started over. However after re adding the textpanel it still didn't appear. I even added the form layout, however still nothing. Anything else you would suggest?

Comment: It is hard to continue to help you with such limited code you have provided

Answer (score 0):

myFrame.getContentPane() returns an AWT container, not a Swing component. To change this you have to use

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(..);
myFrame.setContentPane(panel);
panel.validate();
```

Add your spinners to the panel and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Add spinners to the panel. and then add panel to your JFrame.

```
panel.add(spinner_5);
```